# Why won't this powered hopper stop running?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Goal here is to only allow one item in the bottom hopper at a time. When the furnace fills up and an item enters the bottom hopper, the top hopper becomes powered. In theory, this should stop the top hopper from dropping additional items, but it just keeps dropping them. What am I missing? Latest version of Minecraft Bedrock.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that two stacked hoppers will transfer 2 items at a time. This is because the top hopper "pushes" one item down and the bottom hopper "pulls" a second item down simultaneously. When the top hopper is powered, it stops pushing items down, but the bottom hopper continues to pull items down.